# passing literal in mongoose find() query

Tags: mongoose, literals

I have a variable like:

```
var Collection1 = require('...path to schema');

var schemaName = 'Collection1';
```

I want to be able to do:

```
var cursor = [schemaName].find().cursor();
```

but I keep getting undefined. How can I use a variable to pass into the find() mongoose query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `mongoose.model` to look up a model by its name:

```
var cursor = mongoose.model(schemaName).find().cursor();
```